# Is a linear mixed-effect model the correct approach?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I conducted a crossover study where 10 subjects performed tasks using two different methods (A and B) based on different conditions. 5 of the subjects started with method A and 5 subjects started with method B. After completing the tasks in each method, the remaining method was performed.

During the method, the subjects each performed the same task on 10 different conditions using the respective method. Whereby the 10 conditions always occurred only with 1 subject each. Thus, there were 100 different unique conditions. The time to complete each task was measured.

I formulated this in R with `lmer` as follows:

`TIME~METHOD+ORDER+(1|SUBJECT)`.

Is this the correct approach to find out which method is faster related to a large number of different conditions?

Basically, my point is that we have very few subjects in our studies. But we would like to investigate different methods (e.g. A vs. B). We want to compensate this by multiple measurements, but using different conditions. Is this the correct procedure?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "...which method is **faster** related to a large number of different models?"

Comment: Also, MODEL should not be in your (ahem) model, because it is unique for every combination of SUBJECT and METHOD. You have 100 measurements and 100 MODEL values, so you do not have any degrees of freedom with which to estimate a parameter for MODEL.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a mistake on my part. I meant of course:
TIME~METHOD+ORDER+(1|SUBJECT)

Comment: By faster I mean that method A takes less time to complete the tasks than method B. The time is recorded per model.

Comment: Thanks - please edit your question to reflect that, because not all readers will read comments. Also, it might be helpful if you used a different word for MODEL in your question, because this is already causing confusion with the normal statistical meaning of model. I thought you were concerned about the speed of the computation ("*faster related to a large number of different models*")

Comment: Possibilities you might want to consider: (i) a METHOD*ORDER interaction term, and (ii) random slopes for SUBJECT (possibly insufficient data to do this well without switching to a Bayesian approach).